# Doctrine paginator with sorting not proper with mysql 5.7 version

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have used doctrine paginator for pagination. With previous mysql version 5.5 it was working properly with order by. But after upgrading to mysql version 5.7 it doesn't work properly.
Doctrine orm version is v2.4.8.

Comment: are you able to get raw query run into directly in updated mysql database?

Comment: yes I got query by ```$qb->getQuery()->getSQL()``` and run raw query directly in mysql database it gives proper result but after pagination https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php it doesn't give proper result.

Comment: `it doesn't give proper result.`-> what is `improper`????

Comment: i suggest you to use [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) having multiple features listed on github.

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is not sorting records.

Comment: Can you add a query where you are using it?

Comment: I got my answer from here https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/7083.